# Why do I get an invalid syntax when defining a global variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

```
def pLatin_converter (self):
    movetoend = ""
    index = 0
    global pig = ""
```

I'm getting an 'invalid syntax' on the `global pig = ""` line and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global variable can't be assigned a value in the `global` statement.

Split the two:

```
global pig
pig = ""
```