# Issue global keyword in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python.

I am not understanding why about

- assign after define global variable : valid
- valid but define and assign global variable at once : not valid.

As for example:

```
def Test():
    global a=15
Test()
print(a)
```

**Is invalid while:**

```
def Test():
    global a
    a=15
Test()
print(a)
```

**Is valid**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [invalid syntax, defining global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279682/invalid-syntax-defining-global-variable)

Answer (score 2):

The `global` statement syntax is `global <name>` and just tells the interpreter that you are working with a variable from `globals()` instead of `locals()` for the current scope/frame. It really just tells Python where to grab the variable, and doesn't support assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The `global` keyword tells your interpreter that a variable is a global one. Let's say you have this code:

```py
a = 10
def p():
    a = 20
    print('This is a local:', a)

print("a is unchanged:", 10==a)

def q():
    global a
    a = 40
    print('This is the global:', a)

print("a has changed:", 40==a)
```

Remember, the `global` only tells your interpreter that "There's this variable outside your local variables" when it is called inside functions. Therefore, you cannot assign a value to a variable that you are calling as `global` in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to python as well, so I suppose I'll work this out with you! It looks like it indicates a syntax error at the = sign in line 2. It works in the second example because you declared the variable separately on a new indented line below global? So I'm guessing the first example won't work because the variable is declared along with global?